# In WebForms, why does my anonymous event handler not get called when added after OnLoad?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, webforms, page-lifecycle, anonymous-methods

I have an ASP.NET WebForms page with several buttons added programmatically like this:

```
    private void AddExportButton(Control control, Action clickAction) {
        LinkButton exportButton = new LinkButton {
            Text = "Export",
            EnableViewState = false /*Buttons will be recreated on each Postback anyway.*/
        };
        exportButton.Click += (sender, e) => clickAction();
        control.Controls.Add(exportButton);
    }
```

Now this works, as long as the `AddExportButton()` method is called along the path from the `OnLoad()` or `OnPreLoad()` method. It does not fire the handler action however, when `AddExportButton()` called from the `OnLoadComplete()` method.

I would like to add/create the buttons also when another event handler (coming from a dropdown) gets called. This only happens after the OnLoad(), which will break my code.

Why is this, and **how can I use anonymous methods as event handlers in this case?**

See this nice cheat sheet about the [ASP.NET Page LifeCycle](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/o_aspNet_Page_LifeCycle.jpg) by Léon Andrianarivony for more info about the order of the page/control creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page life cycle, the internal `RaisePostBackEvent` method (which raises the button's `Click` event) occurs **between** `OnLoad` and `OnLoadComplete`. If you wait until `OnLoadComplete` to add the `LinkButton` and hook up its `Click` event, then obviously the event won't be raised: it's too late.

(The fact that you're using an anonymous method is irrelevant.)

Can you add the export button in the .aspx but set its `Visible` property to false when you don't want it to appear?

Comment: Hm, the problem for me is, that there are multiple export buttons to add (And I am doing some other, expensive, stuff, which I did not mention). As said, Depending on the user clicking on the mentioned dropdown on a certain tab control, I want to add a subset of those buttons only. Setting them to invisible is just much work for no relevant outcome. Thus, adding needs to be in reaction of another click event. I can not do earlier, since earlier, the click event of the tab was not handeled. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you post the code for the dropdown's event handler as well? (At least the part that adds the button.)

Comment: That part is already shown, though this code is quite buried under many other calls. I have understood your answer and built it quite like that (Creating the button each time in the OnLoad(), and it works. All event handlers get called as expected, and the unwanted ones are not visible.